# htaccess rewrite rule on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have searched extensively for an answer to this question but none of the suggestions in previous threads have worked for me so I decided to start my own.

I have a website built with wordpress that has a permalink structure for blog posts of domainname.com/blog/postname/. For the sake of maintaining old links, this structure needs to  stay intact. However, the site also has custom post types in a resources section of the site that are now showing up as domainname.com/blog/resources/customposttype/. I would like to change domainname.com/blog/resources/ to just domainname.com/resources/

I have tried a few different ReWrite rules that I found on this site, the latest being RewriteRule ^/blog/resources(.*)$  /resources/$1  [R] but with no luck. If anyone is able to provide a working solution that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a permalink structure that defines the http://www.example.com/blog or is WordPress stored in a subdirectory?

Comment: Used this plugins https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Comment: Yes, it is the wordpress permalink structure that is defining the url. I had tried the custom post type permalink plugin, but it only allows me to modify the permalink structure for custom post types after /blog/